# Python urllib2 crawler crashes router

Tags: python, multithreading, urllib2, web-crawler

I have threaded urllib2 to pull quotes from google finance. By the time the request queue is finished and output stored about as second has elapsed before sending out the new requests, at the moment I'm just checking 10 stocks, so the thread count is 10 per sec. Although my router may not be the best, it crashes under this load.

Is this due to a poorly written crawler? Is there any way to reduce requests/network load without a larger scheduling gap.

Doesn't P2P software send out more requests than this successfully?

Comment: Aside from your router, do you think Google will appreciate having to handle 10 requests per second from you? How about 100? What if 1000 of your fellow developers also think this is a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't suggest crawling anything from Google except for API's or you can expect a ban, filter or law suit (though unlikely), especially not when making something commercial and/or publicly released.

This seems interesting though: http://yken.org/2009/01/05/how-to-get-a-real-time-stock-quote-using-google-api/

And about the router issue, are you sure your router crashes and you aren't getting blocked by Google?

Comment: Point taken re: google, I chose them because I thought they would manage these types of requests (in whatever way). Google don't have a Python stock API, although the aforementioned link looks interesting, this was more an exercise. Regarding the router, it reboots. Re: my original request, are there any efficiencies to be made here?

Comment: Probably, but I'm not an expert so anything I would say would be utter random bullshit :)